# system.security method in pinescript v5 returns wrong values when I try to calculate MACD on other tickers

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following sample code is supposed to calculate MACD for a different ticker name. but it returns wrong values when I check by label.new method. It returns correct `close` but incorrect MACD value. I have used my own `calcMACD` method as well as built-in `ta.macd` both giving wrong values.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5

indicator('test MACD', overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/5

calcMACD(src, fastLength, slowLength, signalLength) =>
    fastMA = ta.ema(src, fastLength)
    slowMA = ta.ema(src, slowLength)
    macd = fastMA - slowMA
    signal = ta.ema(macd, signalLength)
    hist = macd - signal
    [macd, signal]


///////////// Symbols /////////////////
symbol1    = input.symbol("", "Symbol 1", inline="sym1", group="Symbols")

///////////// MACD inputs /////////////////
fastLength   = input.int(title="Fast length", defval=12, inline="FS1", group='MACD')
slowLength   = input.int(title="Slow length", defval=26, inline="FS1", group='MACD')
signalLength = input.int(title="Signal smoothing", minval = 1, maxval = 20, defval = 3,  group='MACD', inline="FS2")
resMACD = input.timeframe(title='Resolution', defval="5", inline='FS2', group='MACD')

//////////// MACD and trend calculations ////////////

closeSymbol1 = request.security(symbol1, resMACD, close)
[macd1, signal1] = calcMACD(closeSymbol1, fastLength, slowLength, signalLength)

[macd2, signal2, hist2] = ta.macd(closeSymbol1, fastLength, slowLength, signalLength)
_macd2 = ta.ema(closeSymbol2, fastLength) - ta.ema(closeSymbol2, slowLength)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_arrowup, text=str.tostring(math.round(closeSymbol1,3))+ " | M1: "+str.tostring(math.round(macd1, 3)) + " | M2: "+str.tostring(math.round(_macd2, 3)), color=color.white)
```

When I run this indicator on SPY and ask it to show me MACD of QQQ all on 5min timeframe (both chart and MACD calculations), I can see different values when I see MACD on QQQ directly. You should select Symbol-1 to e QQQ in the setting of the indicator. [image: Example of seeing 0 for MACD in premarket and some values afetr market open, even though the close values are correct in both premarket and market open.]

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this. I checked all the values and they seem to return correct values. Could you please attach some screenshots and show how they don't match?

Comment: I could not find any error either.

Comment: added a picture.I am getting 0 now. previously, when it as in tradingview strategy format, I was getting nonzero but wrong values, which I have no ide why.

Comment: By double checking the data, I think the problem might be that `input.symbol("", "Symbol 1", inline="sym1", group="Symbols")` does not activate extendedhours and request.security does not return any value on extended hours and that messes up with the ema calculations inside MACD. Not sure how to solve it. One way would be hard coding symbols using `ticker.new` where you can activate extended hour.